# product rule for matrix functions

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

if A,B are matrices, does the product rule hold like i've written it? (It holds if $\vec{x}$ was a scalar. )
$$\frac{d A(\vec{x})B(\vec{x})}{d\vec{x}} = \frac{d A(\vec{x})}{d\vec{x}} B(\vec{x}) + A(\vec{x})\frac{d B(\vec{x})}{d\vec{x}} $$

I do not know what the derivative $\frac{d A(\vec{x})}{d\vec{x}}$ is, so it is difficult to verify the above statement. But in my case, if the above identity holds, then there are eliminations and it is not required to calculate it.

**Extra:** Are there some sources which present the above in an not so formal manner? (I am an engineer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the proposed rule is false, but you can use [index notation](https://www.continuummechanics.org/tensornotationbasic.html) to derive the correct rule
$$\eqalign{
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{d #1}{d #2}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vecc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
P &= AB \\
P_{ij} &= \sum_n A_{in}B_{nj} \\
\grad{P_{ij}}{x_k}
  &= \sum_n \gradLR{A_{in}}{x_k} B_{n j} + A_{in} \gradLR{B_{nj}}{x_k} \\
}$$
This result is a third-order **tensor** which cannot be written using standard matrix notation. The first term on the RHS is especially problematic.

One trick is to [vectorize](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) the equation before differentiating
$$\eqalign{
p &= \vecc{P} \\
  &= \LR{B\otimes I}^Ta  &\doteq\; \LR{I\otimes A}b \\
\grad px
  &=  \LR{B\otimes I}^T\gradLR ax
\;&+\; \LR{I\otimes A}\gradLR bx \\
}$$
Vectorization flattens matrices into vectors, so matrix notation will work again.

To learn more about this subject, explore the [matrix-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix-calculus) tag on this site.

The [Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) is also a handy reference.